# Emulate RPC with Firebase

Tags: firebase

I am using **Firebase** to monitor machines across the building.
So architecture is multiple front-ends and multiple machines.

At a certain moment I want to be able to trigger some actions on these machines like:

- take screenshot and put to ftp
- encode a certain video file
- analyze a large data-set

> I am used to **Actionscript**, there are **NetConnection** and
>   **Client** objects to whom one could invoke remote methods.
>
> - Is there something similar in **Firebase** ?
> - How would you implement such a feature easily ?

I thought of having a *message box*, using an Array, where a **message** could be a data structure like:

```
{ 
  'client_id': 'xxx-yyy-zzz', 
  'name': 'takeScrenshot', 
  'body': { 'creator': 'my-name' },
  'timestamp': 1406214344
}
```

**How it might work**

- a method call is a message entering this message box Array
- listening with value_changed over this message box
- pop item from array (this will trigger another value changed)
- use the item to perform async operation
- when async operation is done, using the client_id, notify the invoker about the operation

But to implement it correctly a lot of work must be done, does anyone know if there is an easy way to achieve this kind of functionality ?

Comment: So you are looking for a remote method invocation framework that uses Firebase? A lot of that depends on the language you intend to implement your clients and servers in.

Comment: Yes, RMI/RPC through Firebase, initially I only need Javascript for the web page based clients and for the server side I use Python with python-firebasin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Firebase is a powerful backend service, scalable, and has a RESTful API in addition to SDKs (not yet for Python, unfortunately), it generally makes the most sense to just use it directly, rather than fashioning API services on top of it.

One fast and effective way to do this is to utilize a [queue approach](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-work-queue). Have each client write data into an `in/` path, and have the recipient of the event listen for `child_added` on that path. Then perform the remote invocation, and write data back to an `out/` path for the requesting client.

**client**

```
// send it
var ref = new Firebase(QUEUE_URL);
var request = ref.child('in').push( requestData );

// wait for a reply and remove after processing
ref.child('out/'+request.name()).on('value', function(snap) {
   if( snap.val() !== null ) {
      console.log(snap.val());
      request.remove();
      // stop listening
      snap.ref().off();
   }
});
```

**remote service**

```
var ref = new Firebase(QUEUE_URL);

// listen for queue events
ref.child('in').on('child_added', function(snap) {
   /*
     ... process queue event ...
    */
   doneProcessing(snap, resultData);
});

function doneProcessing(snap, results) {
   ref.child('out/'+snap.name()).set(results);
   snap.ref().remove();
}
```

Comment: What about responding to the right client ? What about invoking methods with parameters ?

Comment: You write whatever you want into in/; that can be an event to invoke, a list of parameters, etc. Responding to the correct client is done by writing to out/ + snap.name(), which is where the client is listening. Security rules can control read access. This is a technique used in production; it works.